# Export CSV using Smar Table

Tags: angular, csv, smart-table

Have this error Using smart table together with my directive, in my table st-pipe for server side and st-table.

My Table

```
<table st-pipe="callServer"  st-table="displayedClients" class="table" st-filtered-collection="displayedClients">
                .....
</table>
```

My directive

```
app.directive('stFilteredCollection', function () {
        return {

            restrict: 'A',
            require: '^stTable',
            scope: {
                stFilteredCollection: '='
            },
            controller: 'stTableController',
            link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
                console.log(scope.stFilteredCollection);
                scope.$watch(function () {
                    return ctrl.getFilteredCollection();
                }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                    scope.stFilteredCollection = ctrl.getFilteredCollection();
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

My error

```
angular.js:14525 Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives 
[stFilteredCollection (module: myapp), stPipe] asking for new/isolated 
scope on: <table st-pipe="callServer" st-table="displayedClients" 
class="table" st-filtered-collection="displayedClients">
```